# Proving that $x^2 + 4$ is not divisible by $3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I need to show the following:

For any integer $x$, $x^2 + 4$ is not divisible by $3$.

I was trying proof by contraposition, but I do not believe that is the most efficient way to go about this.  Can anybody point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: hint: Consider $0^2, 1^2$ and $2^2$ $\mod 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $x^4 +4$ is divisible by $3$. Then $x^2 + 1 = (x^2 +4) -3$ is divisible by $3$.

Now (following https://math.stackexchange.com/a/630761/26188) you have that one of the following is divisible by $3$:

- $x-1$
- $x$
- $x+1$.
  If $x$ is divisible by $3$, then so is $x^2$ and so $x^2 + 1$ would not be divisible by $3$.

If $x$ is not divisible by $3$, then $x-1$ or $x+1$ would be divisible by $3$. So $(x-1)(x+1) = x^2 -1$ is divisible by $3$. And so then $x^2 + 1 = (x^2 -1) +2$ can't be divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have  $ n \equiv 0,1,2  \text{ mod } 3 $. Hence  $ n^2 \equiv 0,1 \text{ mod } 3 $. Thus  $ n^2+4 \equiv 1,2  \neq 0 \text{ mod } 3 $. So for any integer  $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ,  $ n^2+4$ is not divisible by  $3 $.

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can do this as an exercise in [proof by infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent).  Suppose there were such an $x$.  Since we're squaring it, we can assume $x\ge0$, and it's easy to see that we can assume $x\ge3$ as well, since $4$, $5$, and $8$ are not divisible by $3$.  But if $x^2+4=3k$, then

$$(x-3)^2+4=x^2+4-6x+9=3(k+2x+3)$$

which means there is no minimal counterexample, hence no counterexamples at all.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=3k+a$, where $a=-1,0,1$. Then $$x^2+4=(3k+a)^2+4=3(2ak+3k^2)+(a^2+4)$$ So $3\mid x^2+4\iff 3\mid a^2+4$. Checking the values $a=-1,0,1$ we see that $3\not\mid a^2+4$.

Answer (score -1):

$$x \equiv 0 \equiv 1 \equiv -1 \pmod{3} \space \text{for all cases}$$

Then:

$$x^2 \equiv 0 \equiv 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$

In any of the cases,

$$4 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$

$$x^2 + 4 \equiv 1 \equiv 2 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$$

ALSO:

$$x^2 + 4 = (x + 2)^2 - 4x$$

Suppose it is divisible by $3$ then,

$$x + 2 \equiv 2\sqrt{x} \pmod{3}$$

But $\sqrt{x}$ isn't necessarily an integer, but a remainder is always an integer.