# Is it possible to find an integer, $n$, so that $n^2 + 2$ is divisible by $5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’ve been given this question on a problem set. And I searched it up and I saw something that was similar to my question that said
$$
\textit{Imagine a row of dots and columns}
$$
and it made me even more confused. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Hint: Try looking at the remainder when you divide $n^2 +2$ by $5$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots$. That should suggest a way to prove what you want.

Comment: Ignoring the hint... have you ever seen modular arithmetic before?  What is $0^2\pmod{5}$?  $1^2\pmod{5}$?  $2^2$?  $3^2$?  $4^2$?  Are any of these equivalent to $3\pmod{5}$?  What does this tell you about the possibility of $n^2+2$ being divisible by $5$?

Comment: Any integer has the form $5n,5n\pm1$ or $5n\pm2$. Squaring and adding 2 we get a multiple of 5 plus 2, 3 or 1 respectively. So we can never get a multiple of 5.

Comment: Are there some perfect squares with the last digit 3 or 8?

Comment: Have a look here also at [similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255318/proving-that-x2-4-is-not-divisible-by-3?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible.  Any $n$ is $5k, 5k\pm1$, or $5k\pm2$.

If $n=5k$ then $n^2+2=25k^2+2=5(5k^2)+2$ leaves remainder $2$ when divided by $5$.

If $n=5k\pm1$ then $n^2+2=25k^2\pm10k+1+2=5(5k^2\pm2k)+3$ leaves remainder $3$.

If $n=5k\pm2$ then $n^2+2=25k^2\pm20k+4+2=5(5k^2\pm4k+1)+1$ leaves remainder $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that if a number ends with $1$, then its square will end with $1$.
If a number ends with $2$, then its square will end with $4$.
If a number ends with $3$, then its square will end with $9$.
If a number ends with $4$, then its square will end with $6$.
If a number ends with $5$, then its square will end with $5$.
If a number ends with $6$, then its square will end with $6$.
If a number ends with $7$, then its square will end with $9$.
If a number ends with $8$, then its square will end with $4$.
If a number ends with $9$, then its square will end with $1$.
If a number ends with $0$, then its square will end with $0$.

In none of the above cases I can add $2$ to the number and get either get $0$ or $5$ in the units place. Thus, $n^2+2$ can never be divided by $5$.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to $n^2\equiv -2 \pmod 5$. But $-2 \equiv 3\pmod 5$, so we are looking for a solution to $n^2 \equiv 3\pmod 5$. Since we are working modulo $5$ there are only $5$ possibilities to check:

$0^2 = 0\equiv 0\pmod 5$

$1^2 = 1\equiv 1\pmod 5$

$2^2 = 4\equiv 4\pmod 5$

$3^2 = 9\equiv 4\pmod 5$

$4^2 = 16\equiv 1\pmod 5$

None of these are equivalent to $3 \pmod 5$, so no such $n$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the following table, where each column is the ones digit of an integer $n$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline n & n^2 & n^2 + 2 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 3 \\
2 & 4 & 6 \\
3 & 9 & 1 \\
4 & 6 & 8 \\
5 & 5 & 7 \\
6 & 6 & 8 \\
7 & 9 & 1 \\
8 & 4 & 6 \\
9 & 1 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Since the column $n^2+2$ does not contain any $0$s or $5$s, therefore there are no numbers in the form $n^2+2$ that are divisible by $5$ as that is the requirement for divisibility by $5$.

Comment: This only shows the result for $0\leqslant n\leqslant 9$...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that with the way I've written my answer, each number $n$ is simply truncated to its ones digit.